# Migrating a mysql 4 wtih latin1 charset to mysql 5 with utf8

Tags: character-encoding, migration, mysql

I have a an old mysql 4 database with latin1 character set wtih content in Cyrilic, that I need to migrate in mysql 5 with utf8. When I make the mysql dump I see strange characters and I can make a prorper recovery.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a dump with the parameter --default-character-set set to the value of the source database (latin 1), change the charset od the db and tables in the txt file  and the restore it with the charset of the target database (utf8):

Here is the procedure how to do it:

http://itworkarounds.blogspot.com/2011/07/mysql-database-migration-and-character.html

Comment: Downvoted because the linked ressource is dangerously misleading: the sed command changes every appearance of latin1 to utf8 - even within the data.